# Creating a Pull Request in Azure Devops (using REST API) doesn't link work items

Tags: python, git, azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to automate some post-release processes for creating Pull Requests (release branch -> master) after a release.  While I'm able to automate the PR creation, and it links the commits, it does not link the work items.

Note: I'm using Python for this, using the (officially supported) azure-devops module from PyPi (https://pypi.org/project/azure-devops/).  It is a thin wrapper around the REST API, and I've read the REST API documentation itself to see if there are any other options (haven't found any so far).  Here's my code:

```
def create_pull_request(self, repo_id, source_branch, target_branch, title, description):

    pull_request = {
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/" + source_branch,
        "targetRefName": "refs/heads/" + target_branch,
    }
    response = self._git_client.create_pull_request(pull_request, repository_id=repo_id)
```

Here's my function for connection to the git client:

```
def __init__(self, personal_access_token=None, organization_url=None):
    # Create a connection to the org
    credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
    self._connection = azure.devops.connection.Connection(base_url=organization_url,
                                                         creds=credentials)

    # Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
    self._git_client = self._connection.clients.get_git_client()
```

I've also tried pulling the individual commits to see if I can find the work items associated with them and attached them to the pull request after creation, but those responses are coming back with the work items empty.

Is there some other way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ideas to get your work items linked:

First, your `pull_request` should probably include:

```py
    pull_request = {
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/" + source_branch,
        "targetRefName": "refs/heads/" + target_branch,
        "workItemRefs": # collection of work item refs
    }
```

`workItemRefs` is documented in the REST API docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 . What you need to put in there is probably a matter of some experimentation.

Second, as an alternative, your commits could be created in the form:

```
git commit -m "My commit message #workitemid1 #workitemid2, etc."
```

Then, when the PR is created, it will automatically link those work items in the commits it finds in the PR.

Comment: Where would I get that list of work items from though?  I was thinking that I could create the PR without any work items, then get the list of commits from the created PR and query those commits for their work items, but they are coming back without any.  When I look at them in azure devops I can confirm that they are linked to work items.

Comment: Can you try doing a commit with the syntax I suggested, create a PR and see if the work item links?

Comment: I'll try it, but it's not really a solution for my use case.  We have a number of developers working, so that policy won't consistently be followed.  I'd have to have a secondary solution anyways.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot add work item link via the Pull Request Create API and Pull Request Update API. I found a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-dev-ops-api-pull-request-update-ability-to-a/911435), you could follow the ticket to get the latest news.

As a work item, we could link work item to pull request via this REST API [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-link)

Steps:

Get pull request field `artifactId` via below API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=6.0
```

Link work item to Pull Request:

Request URL:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{work item ID}?api-version=5.1
```

Request Body:

```
[ {
  "op": "add", 
  "path": "/relations/-",
  "value": {
    "rel": "ArtifactLink",
    "url": "{This url is artifactId}",
    "attributes": { 
        "name": "pull request" 
    }
  }
} ]
```

Result:

[image]

**Update1**

> Is there somewhere that I could find the work items associated with the commits

We could list the work items associated via the commit ID.

Request URL:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/wit/artifactUriQuery?api-version=5.0-preview
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "artifactUris": [
    "vstfs:///Git/Commit/{Project ID}%2F{Repo ID}%2F{Commit ID}"
  ]
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there somewhere that I could find the work items associated with the commits, because when I query the commits (after creating the PR) the work items is coming back empty.  The issue here is that I want to include the same list of work items that is created when you create a PR though the GUI.  And additional Release work item would be nice, but I'm mostly concerned with discovering the work items and associating them.

They'll be different every time (for each PR), so I need something I can dynamically query.

Comment: Hi @DerianReuss, We could find the work items associated with the commits, I have updated the answer, please check the update1, then kindly share the result here, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi @DerianReuss, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API '[CommitsBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)' that can return all the commits between 2 branches. This API has a boolean parameter 'includeWorkItems' that will return the linked work items. You can pull out a unique list of Workitems from that response to use in the PR creation.